# Angular 7: Why do I have to call my subscribe method twice for it to take affect

Tags: angular, scope, rxjs, angular2-observables, subscribe

I think I am misunderstanding Subscriptions and Observables and I am not finding the Angular documentation particularly helpful.

I am creating a validationService meant to check if a username is available. The validationService is called on form submit and will display an error message if the username is unavailable. The problem is, i have to submit the form twice for it to work.

The validationService makes a http call to the backend that returns a boolean. I have a local variable 'availableUsername' that I want to set the result to, so that I can use it elsewhere. Inside the subscribe function it works fine, I get the result and I set it to this variable. But when I leave the scope of the subscribe method, the variable is undefined. But when I call submit again, it works.

I have added the validationService and userService below.

validationService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { AlertService } from './../services/alert.service';
import { UserService } from './../services/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ValidationService {

  availableUsername: boolean;
  availableEmail: boolean;

  constructor(
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private userService: UserService
    ) { }

  validateUsername(controls: any): boolean {

    const username = controls.username.value;

    this.isUsernameAvailable(username);

    if (!this.availableUsername) {
      this.alertService.error('This username is already taken', false);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private isUsernameAvailable(username: string) {

    if (username === undefined || username === '') {
      return;
    }

    this.userService.isUserNameAvailable(username)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.availableUsername = result;
    },
    error => {
      this.alertService.error(error);
      return;
    });
  }

}
```

userService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {

  apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  isUserNameAvailable(username: string) {
    return this.http.get<boolean>(`${this.apiUrl}/users/checkUsernameAvailability/${username}`);
  }

}
```

Comment: The A in AJAX means **asynchronous**. The function passed to subscribe(), which initializes `this.availableUsername`, is executed loooooong after your validator has returned its result. You need to use an asyncValidator. But most importantly, you need to understand the principle of asynchrony.

Comment: So validateUsername isn't waiting for isUsernameAvailable to finish?

Comment: Yes, it does. And as you can see, isUsername doesn't return anything. All it does is to send a http request and return immediately. At that time, isUsernameAvailable() has finished. The response to the request, however, will be handled by the callback, much later. Just like, if I tell you "please toast me a piece of bread", you'll have finished that task in 2 seconds: the time it takes to put the bread in the toaster. I will only be able to eat the toast much later though: when the toaster rings to notify me that the toast is ready.

Comment: And while the toaster is slowly toasting the bread, you and I do plenty of other things.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.isUsernameAvailable(username);
```

when the above this line of code is excuted it will run asynchronously  so before assigning a value to  `this.availableUsername = result;`
by the subscription the below code will run

```
 if (!this.availableUsername) {
      this.alertService.error('This username is already taken', false);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

To avoid that what have to do is check this condition inside the subscription like this

```
     this.userService.isUserNameAvailable(username)
          .subscribe((result) => {
            this.availableUsername = result;
        },
        error => {
          this.alertService.error(error);
          return;
        }
         ()=>{
 if (!this.availableUsername) {
      this.alertService.error('This username is already taken', false);

    }
}
);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is that you trying to use **asynchronous** flow **synchronously**
the `availableUsername` property value will set only when the `subscribe` call back is called, which will be long after the `if (!this.availableUsername)`.

in this case you could use [asyncValidartor](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator) which built for those cases.

Another (less recommended) alternative is making your code run synchronously use `async` and `await`.